# How to show a message when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to show the following message when the button below is clicked using jQuery

```
<p class="msg-confirm" id="msgConf">
  Great! You got this. Let's continue.
</p>
```

Button:

```
<input type="button" value="Start" class="btn-start" id="exec">
```

This message is set as none in CSS:

```
.msg-confirm{
display: none;
```

}

I have this function that worked before on a similar context, but without the validation. If the checkbox below is checked, I want this function working.

```
    $("#exec").click(function(){
    if($('#d3').is(':checked')){
        $("#msgConf").show('slow');
    }
});
```

Checkbox:

```
<input type="radio" name="image" id="d3" class="input-step1 aheadF1"/>
```

Comment: This code is already working...

Comment: @mindmaster It was not. I put the validation in the end of the code, so it was not undertanding for some reason. I have a lot of validation before this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#exec").on("click",function (){
    if($('#d3').is(':checked')){
       $("#msgConf").css("display","")
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't know why this was accepted. It's functionally equivalent to what the OP has

Answer (score 1):

Let's make use of the simplicity of some of the new features of jQuery such as the [.prop() method](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) that will allow us to verify if a checkbox or radio button is checked. For the purpose of this example, I switched the input to a checkbox since it is more appropriate UX/UI wise speaking, however, this property can be verified in both controls.  We will use the [toggleClass() method](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) of jQuery to toggle the class that hides the P tag and its content initially. I certainly hope this helps.

*Happy coding!*

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#exec").click(function () {
        if ($('#d3').prop('checked')) {
            $("p").toggleClass("msg-confirm");
        } else {
            alert("Please select the checkbox to display info.");
        } 
    }); 
});
```

```css
.msg-confirm {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="msg-confirm">
  Great! You got this. Let's continue.
</p>
<input type="button" value="Start" class="btn-start" id="exec">
<input type="checkbox" name="image" id="d3" class="input-step1 aheadF1"/>
```